# How to use webklex AttachmentMask class getContentBase64Encoded or getImageSrc

Tags: laravel, imap

I am having problems using the getImageSrc and getContentBase64Encoded under the AttachmentMask::class webklex.

The error message shows Method `Webklex\IMAP\Message::getImgSrc()` is not supported and Method `Webklex\IMAP\Message::getContentBase64Encoded ()` is not supported.

```
$oClient = new Client([
 'host'          => $imap['host'],
'port'          => $account->imap_port_no,
'encryption'    => $ssl,
'validate_cert' => true,
'username'      => $account->user_name,
'password'      => $account->password,
]);

$oFolder = $oClient->getFolder($folder_name);
$oMessage = $oFolder->getMessage($message_id, null, null, true, true, true);

$test = $oMessage->getImgSrc();
    //or this
$test = $oMessage->getContentBase64Encoded();
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working already using these line of codes.

```
$attachment_mask = \Webklex\IMAP\Support\Masks\AttachmentMask::class;

    $oClient->setDefaultAttachmentMask($attachment_mask);
    $attachment  = $oMessage->getAttachments()->first();
    $masked_attachment = $attachment->mask();

    $link = $masked_attachment->getImageSrc()
```

;